# Is Adamantium common?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk, adamantium

In issue 5 of the recent Incredible Hulk ongoing (vol. 3), it is revealed that

> Dr. Doom

separated the Incredible Hulk and Bruce Banner. He does this using **an adamantium chainsaw**.

[image: Definitely not Dr. Doom]
<sup>Image blurred to protect the <s>innocent</s> spoiler.</sup>

I was under the impression that adamantium was pretty much impossible to find and use outside of Ultron and the Weapon Blah program. Is it common enough that it's no big deal for the blurry fellow above to have gotten an adamantium chainsaw?

Comment: +1 for going to the effort of spoiler-preventing an image!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Marvel wiki:](http://marvel.com/universe/Adamantium)

> Extraordinarily expensive to produce, Adamantium is created through the mixing of certain chemical resins whose exact composition is a closely guarded government secret. For eight minutes after the resins are mixed, Adamantium can be molded if kept at a temperature of 1,500 degrees Fahrenheit. Its extremely stable molecular structure prevents it from being molded further, even if the temperature remains high enough to keep it in liquefied form. Hardened Adamantium can only be altered by rearrangement of its molecular structure. Given sufficient mass, Adamantium could survive a direct hit from a nuclear weapon or a blow from the most powerful superhuman. The only known substance able to pierce Adamantium is the compound known as Antarctic Vibranium, also called "anti-metal".
>
> The U.S. government has shared the secret of Adamantium’s composition with certain allies, through the information has fallen into unauthorized hands. Attempts by the former Solviet Union to reproduce the metal resulted in the creation of Carbonadium, a weaker yet far more malleable form that was used to create retractable coils wielded by the Russian super-soldier Omega Red. Due to the prohibitive cost of Adamantium’s creation, many parties have resorted to the use of a somewhat weaker compound named Secondary Adamantium, which was once used to coat the sentient computer named F.A.U.S.T..

Given who the individual wielding the adamantium chainsaw is and his scientific ability and wealth he could have either stolen it, actually bought it, or stolen the formula for it.

Comment: \*gasp\* You mean the X-Men movies got it *wrong*? (One of them featured a tank of liquid adamantium, with a character saying something about the necessity of keeping it liquid since it's essentially indestructible once solidified.)